# Express middleware to check ID's not working, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

currently developping a project with **Node js** using **Express** and **MongoDb** for the back-end.
For this project the **USERS** are allowed to post **COMMENTS** so I have created this middleware to access the **DELETE** route checking if the **USER ID** is the same **ID** of the person who created the **COMMENT** with the reference (**postedBy**) inside each **COMMENT**.

My middleware runs and logs both the **USER ID** and the **ID** of the creator of the **COMMENT**(**postedBy**).
In my middleware I stated that: if both **ID's** are the same the **USER** is allowed to continue using **NEXT** and pass onto the next middleware otherwise send an error message of **forbidden**.

As I said; I see in my console both **ID's** but even both being the same or different my middleware always gives me the message of **forbidden** and wont delete the comment. Just as if they are never the same even in the log I can see the same **ID's**.

**Anyone has an idea why this is happening or what am I doing wrong?**

For the record I am new developper and sorry for my amateur code :). I am working on getting better.

Thanks in advance for any help.

This is my route with the middleware:

```
// DELETE COMMENT
router.delete('/:commentId', verifyToken, verfyUserIdPostedBy, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const removedComment = await Comment.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.commentId });
        res.json(removedComment);
    } catch(err){
        res.json({message:err});
    }
})
```

And here is mi middleware:

```
const Comment = require('../models/Comment');


module.exports.verfyUserIdPostedBy = async function (req, res, next) {
      userId = req.header('userId')
      postedById = await Comment.findById({ _id: req.params.commentId});  // query of postedBy 
      console.log(postedById.postedBy._id)
      console.log(userId)
      if(userId === postedById.postedBy._id) {
        next() // role is allowed, so continue on the next middleware 
        return
      }
        res.send('Forbidden')
    
      
}
```

As you can see in my middleware I do a console.log of both values and in the picture both are the same:

[image: As you can see in my middleware I do a console.log of both values and in the picture both are the same]

But eventhough the values are the same I get the forbidden message.

Mario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As looking at your code,

the typeof `userId` == 'string'
but the typeof `postedById.postedBy._id` == 'ObjectId'

so when you're performing strict check using `===` it gives false!

#### Solution

1. convert to string --> `postedById.postedBy._id.toString()`

Or

2. just compare with `==`

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is also a solution

Comment: Your Welcome. Keep Learning Keep Growing!

Answer (score 1):

The following line returns a mongoose document

```
postedById = await Comment.findById({ _id: req.params.commentId});
```

You should use [.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to return a plain object

```
postedById = await Comment.findById({ _id: req.params.commentId}).lean();
```

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain
> javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents. They have no save method,
> getters/setters, virtuals, or other Mongoose features.

Comment: Thanks for info, I passed a few days blocked on this, now the middleware is working just fine.